# Converting a user input string to list

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Is there any way in which I can convert a string to list separated by spaces.The string has to be entered by the user.
Suppose `How are you today ?` is the string entered by the user,I want to store it in a list say L,
`L=['How','are','you','today','?']`. How can I do this??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert string to list in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224717/convert-string-to-list-in-prolog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**?- split_string("How are you today ?", " ", "", L).**

per [this](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=split_string/4) site.

Comment: this is giving me folllowing error-
`ԀERROR: main/0: Undefined procedure: split_string/4
   Exception: (7) split_string([97, 46, 98, 46, 99, 46, 100], [46], [], _G1077) ?`

Comment: split_string works in SWI-Prolog version 7. 
instead ?- atomic_list_concat(L, ' ', 'How are you today ?').

Answer (score 0):

SWI-Prolog offers [tokenize_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=tokenize_atom/2)

```
?- [library(porter_stem)].
?- tokenize_atom('How are you today ?', L).
L = ['How', are, you, today, ?].
```

note that quoting atoms is necessary only when the lexical representation aliases some other *type* (notably variables)